# VS Code - small-ci

Tags: visual-studio-code

From time to time the VS Code Output window opens showing me the output of small-ci How do I deactivate this? I don't know what plugin belongs to small-ci.

[image: small-ci screenshot]

The plugins that I have currently installed are:

- Beautify
- Bookmarks
- Bracket Pair Colorizer 2
- ci-snippets2
- Live Server
- Live Share
- Material Icon Theme
- open in browser
- PHP Debug
- PHP DocBlocker
- PHP Intelephense
- PHP IntelliSense
- PHP IntelliSense for codeigniter
- PHP Server
- Python

Comment: it is couse by php intellisense for codeigniter...

Answer (score 2):

The plugin that is causing this is PHP IntelliSense for codeigniter

Comment: Thank you, the error from this plugin is very disgusting